# convert hex formatted data into string

Tags: delphi, hex

I have some data formatted in hex (stored in byte) that i need to convert to string, the data should be like this

```
13 61 23 45 67 8F FF
```

and expected output

```
13612345678FFF
```

i know Chr() or IntToStr() function will not work since this data not actual hex code but string/number formatted in hex, so anyone has some suggestion for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for converting a dynamic array of bytes to a hex string:

```
function BytesToHex(aSource: TBytes): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(aSource) * 2);
  if Length(aSource) > 0 then
    BinToHex(aSource[0], PChar(Result), Length(aSource));
end;
```

If your source bytes are not in a dynamic array, you'll have to adjust the code slightly, but it should give you a general idea of how to do it.

Comment: what is TBytes? it's undeclared identifier on Delphi 7

Comment: well, you didn't specify what version of Delphi you are using. TBytes = array of Byte

Comment: thanks :D seems TBytes didn't available on D7, btw from which version TBytes available?

Comment: Check Types.pas (which I think was available in D7) for "TByteDynArray = array of Byte;", you can just define TBytes=TByteDynArray. I'm not 100% sure when TBytes was introduced, at a guess, with D2005.

Comment: @Thorsten It's better to do this with an open array anyway, using TBytes is unnecessarily restrictive. Just replace function definition with: `function BytesToHex(const aSource: array of Byte): string;`. This then allows you total flexibility from the caller side. Also use const to avoid unnecessary implicit try/finally blocks.

Comment: @David, you are right on both points. It's just that I copied that source out of a part of NexusDB where it was only used for dynamic arrays and only used for debugging purposes, so not at all time critical. Also, that code was really only meant as an example of how to call the BinToHex from SysUtils, depending on where exactly the bytes are stored that the questioner wants to convert, he is probably better off not to bother with any "array of byte", be it a dynamic array or an open array parameter, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With the example that you've provided, why don't you just remove the spaces?

```
s := '13 61 23 45 67 8F FF';

stripped := StrUtils.ReplaceStr(s,' ','');
```

if your hex string is not too long, you can get it as a number like this:

```
MyInt64 := StrToInt64('$' + stripped);
```

Check out `HexToBin()` if you want to get your hex string as an array of bytes.

Comment: it's not string, 13 61 23 45 67 8F FF is in hex so it read 0x13 0x61 etc on byte

Comment: +1 for showing the opposite way the OP needed; now this questions has both directions in a concise way.